# Does a Gaussian random walk lead to a Gaussian distribution in the limit, even when the initial state is non-Gaussian?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-walk, probability-limit-theorems, gaussian

Suppose we have an initial random variable, which is not Gaussian, but has mean $0$, std $1$.  Now we add $N$ unit Gaussian variables to this initial random variable, and then renormalize to mean $0$, std $1$.  Call the resulting random variable $Z$.

In the limit as $N$ goes to infinity, is $Z$ a unit Gaussian distribution?

Comment: I think it's even true when you don't add Gaussian variables, but variables of some other distribution instead, because of the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem).

Comment: In fact, the Lyapunov CLT implies convergence in distribution to a standard normal random variable, even when the independent random variables being added are not from the same distribution, as long as the absolute value of the random variables all have moments of order $2 + \delta$ for some fixed $\delta>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables. A few facts:

- $\operatorname{E}[X + Y] = \operatorname{E}[X] + \operatorname{E}[Y]$
- If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $\operatorname{Var}(X + Y) = \operatorname{Var}(X) + \operatorname{Var}(Y)$.
- If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and Gaussian, then $X$ + $Y$ is also Gaussian.

So adding $N$ unit Gaussian variables is the same as adding one Gaussian variable with mean 0 and variance $N$. Let's call this variable $G_N$.

Now let $X$ be our initial random variable. After adding the Gaussian we have:

- $\operatorname{E}[X + G_N] = 0$
- $\operatorname{Var}(X + G_N) = 1 + N$

Then we can do:
$$
\begin{array}{}
Z &=& \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{X + G_N}{\sqrt{1 + N}} \\
&=& \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{X}{\sqrt{1 + N}} + \frac{G_N}{\sqrt{1 + N}} \\
&=& \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{X}{\sqrt{1 + N}} + G_\frac{N}{1+N} \\
&=& G_1
\end{array}
$$
Because $\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + N}} = 0$ and $\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{N}{1 + N} = 1$.

Comment: I think the notation $G_1$ is confusing, because you used that for both the first Gaussian random variable that was added to $X$, and the distribution of the limit.